# CSS :first child on link class not working

Tags: css

I have these two elements:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand collapse-award"></a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand collapse-award"></a>
</div>
```

and I am trying to apply :first-child :last-child on these items, but its not working does first and last child only apply for list items ?

```
.navbar-header .collapse-award:first-child {
        max-height: 50px;
}

.navbar-header .collapse-award:last-child {
        max-height: 80px;
        margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: it works on any kind of element, but they must be the first/last children of a container. (*but for `height` use the display type must support it*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) (not voting to close though..)

Comment: they are block elements, they have a navbar-brand class also applied to them, but I just didnt include it because it has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: Then the rules are either being overridden or you're not showing all of the (relevant) HTML. Please include as much code as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for a workin example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwVErQ

```
<div>
   <a href="#" class="collapse-award">item 1</a>
   <a href="#" class="collapse-award">item 2</a>
</div>

.collapse-award:last-child {
    max-height: 80px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    color:#FF0000;
}
.collapse-award:first-child {
    max-height: 50px;
    color:#00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
:first-of-type
```

and

```
:last-of-type
```

if you want to work with the anchor elements and not with child elements and give the anchor elements a

```
 display: inline-block
```

to get the styles working.